# leetcode palindrome question shows error for my solution

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing the leetcode question where we have to find if a number is palindrome or not. I wrote a solution in my vs code and it works but it dosen't work in the leetcode IDE. I know my solution isn't the best but I would like to know where I am doing it wrong.

```
class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    def isPalindrome(self):
        main_list = []
        converted_num = str(self.x)

        for x in converted_num:
            main_list.append(x)

        main_list.reverse()
        str1 = ""

        for ele in main_list:
            str1 += ele

        print(str1 == self.x)

p1 = Solution("11511")
p1.isPalindrome()
```

The error that leetcode shows me is this

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
    ret = Solution().isPalindrome(param_1)
Line 39 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 49 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Here is the link to that question:

https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/

It works on my personal IDE but not on leetcode IDE

(edit)
this is the new code without **init**:

```
class Solution(object):

    def isPalindrome(self, x):

        orig = x

        main_list = []
        converted_num = str(x)

        for x in converted_num:
             main_list.append(x)
        main_list.reverse()

        str1 = ""
         
        for ele in main_list:
            str1 += ele

        return (str1 == orig)
```

Comment: Why are you taking argument in the `__init__()`? The leetcode expects no args in `__init__()` either as you can see in the `ret = Solution().isPalindrome(param_1)` line of the error trace and that is why the error. You could remove the `__init__()` altogether and pass the argument to `isPalindrome()` method

Comment: @kuro  added the new version can you please check it, it always returns false

Comment: in your latest code you are checking the `str1` with `orig` where `orig` is a integer I think and `str1` is a string. Convert `orig` to string before/during check